# How to properly parse a Firestore API JSON?

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Google Cloud Firestore API for a project that involves simple retrieval of data from the server database. Having set up everything I can't seem to figure out how to properly parse the returned JSON, as all of my attempts have been unsuccessful.
Using the Firestore package is out of question as this is a defined project.

I have tried the classic approach since Android studio only gets the field part with its HTTPURLConnection.
This is the JSON structure:

```
{
    "documents": [
    {
        "name": "projects/...",
        "fields": {
            "name": {
                "stringValue": "Q1"
            },
            "myValues": {
                "arrayValue": {
                    "values": [
                    {
                        "stringValue": "First"
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "index": {
                "integerValue": "0"
            }
        },
        "createTime": "2019-05-24T10:07:10.864421Z",
        "updateTime": "2019-05-28T07:52:34.445600Z"
    }
    ]
}
```

Here's my attempt at parsing it:

```java
public ArrayList<Question> parse(String json)
{
    ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();
    try {
        int indeks=0;
        String qName="";
        ArrayList<String> answerList= new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray dokumenti = object.getJSONArray("documents");
        for (int j = 0; j < dokumenti.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jObject = dokumenti.getJSONObject(j);
            if (jObject.has("index")) indeks = jObject.getInt("index");
            if (jObject.has("name")) qName= jObject.getString("name");
            JSONArray answerArray= jObject.getJSONArray("myValues");
            for (int i = 0; i < answerArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    String answer= answerArray.getString(i);
                    answerList.add(answer);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("OOPS", qName);
                }
            }
        }
        list.add(new Question(qName, qName, answerList, answerList.get(indeks), 0));
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        //something
    }
    return list;
}
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmH68.png)

I expect that all of the documents get parsed and added to the `list` ArrayList but it seems like nothing happens and I can't find the TAG in the Logcat.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't see how it's relevant but sure, I updated the post.

Comment: Please also add the content of your `bGe5 ... x6Bg` document. So basically you are trying to get the data of a single document, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo But the content of it is on the right side in the screenshot? I am trying to get all of them from the collection, there might be more, I just added a spoof example for testing.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, didn't see that. Will an answer using a `get()` call on your document reference helping you?

Comment: @AlexMamo Whatever works and doesn't use the Firebase library is a good answer.

Comment: Why not to use Firebase library?

Comment: @AlexMamo Don't know honestly, I guess the senior wants us to go full REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you're trying to get `index` before accessing its parent `fields`.

```
if (jObject.has("index")) indeks = jObject.getInt("index");
```

In this line you should have gotten before the parent object `fields`, otherwise you will not have access to `index` or `name`.

**EDIT**

I've been checking your code and you are parsing some things wrong.
Let's go step by step:

1. You are trying to access to the childs of `fields` without accessing to their parent.
   The solution following your structure would be something like this:

```
JSONObject jObject = dokumenti.getJSONObject(j);
JSONObject fields = jObject.getJSONObject("fields");
if (fields.has("index") && fields.getJSONObject("index").has("integerValue")) {
    indeks = fields.getJSONObject("index").getInt("integerValue");
}
if (fields.has("name") && fields.getJSONObject("name").has("stringValue")) {
    qName = fields.getJSONObject("name").getString("stringValue");
}
```

2. You're trying to access also the `myValues` array not respecting the objects hierarchy. The correct way should be something like this:

```
JSONArray answerArray = fields.getJSONObject("myValues").getJSONObject("arrayValue").getJSONArray("values");
for (int i = 0; i < answerArray.length(); i++) {
   try {
      String answer = answerArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("stringValue");
      answerList.add(answer);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.d("OOPS", qName);
   }
}
```

With this changes I have been able to parse the Json you posted without any problem. Here you can find the complete code:

```
public ArrayList<Question> parse(String json)
    {
        ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();
        try {
            int indeks = 0;
            String qName = "";
            ArrayList<String> answerList = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray dokumenti = object.getJSONArray("documents");
            for (int j = 0; j < dokumenti.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jObject = dokumenti.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONObject fields = jObject.getJSONObject("fields");
                if (fields.has("index") && fields.getJSONObject("index").has("integerValue")) {
                    indeks = fields.getJSONObject("index").getInt("integerValue");
                }
                if (fields.has("name") && fields.getJSONObject("name").has("stringValue")) {
                    qName = fields.getJSONObject("name").getString("stringValue");
                }
                JSONArray answerArray = fields.getJSONObject("myValues").getJSONObject("arrayValue").getJSONArray("values");
                for (int i = 0; i < answerArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        String answer= answerArray.getString(i);
                        answerList.add(answer);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        Log.d("OOPS", qName);
                    }
                }
            }
            list.add(new Question(qName, qName, answerList, answerList.get(indeks), 0));
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            //something
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: If you mean doing something like:                                                                  
`JSONObject jObject2 = dokumenti.getJSONObject(j);
JSONObject jObject = jObject2.getJSONObject("fields");`

and then doing jObject.has("Something") I already tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you should parse the `fields` object before parsing the objects inside. Which part is not being parsed?
Are you able to parse at least the `documents` array?

Comment: Well all I know is that the method returns an empty arraylist and there are (apparently) no exceptions, it's kinda hard to know what happened when the people who designed these JSON functions made it exception-proof unless you really screw it up.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Take a look at it please. @123rightback123

Comment: Thank you very much @Jaime Suárez, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript example:**

```
function toValue(field) {
  return "integerValue" in field
    ? Number(field.integerValue)
    : "doubleValue" in field
    ? Number(field.doubleValue)
    : "arrayValue" in field
    ? field.arrayValue.values.map(toValue)
    : "mapValue" in field
    ? toJSON(field.mapValue)
    : Object.entries(field)[0][1];
}

function toJSON(doc) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(doc.fields ?? {}).map(([key, field]) => [key, toValue(field)])
  );
}
```